# BlogEngine 3.3.6.0 and users

Tags: blogengine.net

I've created my blog with [BlogEngine](https://blogengine.io/) a long time ago. I update it a couple of months ago to the version 3.3.6.0. Now I can't find how to create new users.

I don't know if this is related to another action I did. Basically, I lost my password and I deleted from `users.xml` my password and now I have access with the default password.

Answer (score 3):

add this line to your webconfig:

```
<configuration>
. 
. 
. 
  <appSettings>
    <!-- Override default application settings here -->
    <!-- blog usage scenario: singleblog, multiusers or multiblogs -->
    <add key="BlogEngine.UsageScenario" value="multiusers" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

user Tab will show up when you log in to your administrator account